# Error "fn is not a function" (discord.js bot)

Tags: discord.js

I am getting the following error:

```js
TypeError: fn is not a function - 
at Map.find (c:\Users\soric\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:160:17) - 
at Client.<anonymous> (c:\Users\soric\Desktop\Discord Bot\index.js:162:111) - 
at Client.emit (events.js:322:22) - 
at MessageCreateAction.handle (c:\Users\soric\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14) - 
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (c:\Users\soric\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
```

Code:

```js
case 'mute':
if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.channel.send(" You don't the permission for that!");

let person = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.find(args[1]))
if (!person) return message.reply("Player not found, he's hiding somewhere!");

let mainrole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Gangster");
let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Muted");

if (!muterole) return message.reply("Couldn't find the mute role!");
let time = args[2];

if (!time) {
  return message.reply("You didn't specify a time!");

}
person.removeRole(mainrole.id);
person.addRole(muterole.id);

message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has now been muted for ${ms(ms(time))} `);

setTimeout(function () {
  person.addRole(mainrole.id);
  person.removeRole(muterole.id);
  message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has been unmuted!`)
}, ms(time));


break;
```

Comment: In the code you've posted there ins't even word `fn`

Comment: I know, that's why i'm asking for help, i don't understand why this error shows up

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: What version of discord.js and node are you running?

Comment: Discord.js: 12.2.0 and node.js 12.16.3

Comment: Could you post the full error?

Comment: Please edit extra information into your question next time. That being said, could you show the code snippet for index.js at line 160?

Comment: I don't know how to show the entire error properly because if I copy paste it it's hard to read, is it ok if i make an imgur link and send it to you?

And my 160 line: ` if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.channel.send(" You don't the permission for that!");`

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/pCiZWKy)

Answer (score 0):

`message.guild.roles.cache.find(args[1]))` on line 3 of the piece of code you showed us

The `.find` method always takes a function, not a string. I assume you are supposed to be using `.get` instead of `.find`.

Hope i could help!